# Dropdownlistfor not emptying after having interaction with it

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to emptying a dropdownlist created by a Dropdownlistfor

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id2, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.List2)
```

after changing the selected value of another dropdownlistfor

```
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Id1, (List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.List1)
```

This is my javascript code

```
        function changeList(value, that) {
            //value is equal to the selected value of List2
            var self = $(that).find("#Id2");
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("method", "controller")',
                method: 'POST',
                data: { 'value': value },
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    self.empty();
                    $.each(data, function (key, item) {
                        self.append($("<option></option>").val(item.Value).text(item.Text));
                    });
                },
                error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                }
            });
        }
```

My problem is, when I change the selected value of List1, it manage to change the options of List2, but it doesn't display it.

It works when I don't click or have any interaction with List2 before changing selected value of List1.

It doesn't if I change the selected value of List 2 and then changing the selected value of List 1. (Well it works, but it won't display it correctly to the view).

EDIT

=>My javascript works<=, it won't just displaying it correctly to the view if I interact with it before changing my selected value of List 1 !

EDIT 2

My method in controller

```
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult method(long value)
    {
        try
        {
            var items= GetItems(value);
            return Json(new List<SelectListItem>(items));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Json(new { Result = Error, ex.Message });
        }
    }
```

Comment: what does your controller action looks like which is called in ajax call code?

Comment: Post edited (see edit 2)

Comment: Where and how are you calling`changeList()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, I had to put those two lines after the loop each

```
self.selectmenu("instance").destroy();
self.selectmenu({});
```

I forgot the fact that I am using jquery .. sorry all